# Aggregating customer spend without any customer ID

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I  have 2 columns as below. The first column is spend, and the second column is months from offer. Unfortunately there is no ID to identify each customer. In the case below, there are three customers. e.g. The first 5 rows represent customer 1, the next 3 rows are customer 2, and then final 7 rows are customer 3. You can tell by looking at the months_from_offer, which go from -x to x months for each customer (x is not necessarily the same for each customer, as shown here where x=2,1,3 respectively for customers 1,2,3).

What I am looking to do is calculate the difference in post offer spend vs pre-offer spend for each customer. I don't care about the individual customers themselves, but I would like an overview - e.g. 10 customers had a post/pre difference in between $0-$100.

As an example with the data below, to calculate the post/pre offer difference for customer 1, it is `-$10 - $32 + $23 + $54 = $35`

for customer 2: `-$21 + $87 = $66`

for customer 3: `-$12 - $83 - $65 + $80 + $67 + $11 = -$2`

```
spend  months_from_offer
$10    -2
$32    -1
$43     0
$23     1
$54     2
$21    -1
$23     0
$87     1
$12    -3
$83    -2
$65    -1
$21     0
$80     1
$67     2
$11     3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can identify the customers using the following and then groupby customer:

```
df['customer'] = df['months_from_offer'].cumsum().shift().eq(0).cumsum().add(1)
#Another way to calculate customer per @teylyn method
#df['customer'] = np.sign(df['months_from_offer']).diff().lt(0).cumsum().add(1)

df['amount'] = df['spend'].str[1:].astype(int) * np.sign(df['months_from_offer']
df.groupby('customer')['amount'].sum().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   customer  amount
0         1      35
1         2      66
2         3      -2
```

How it is done:

```
  spend  months_from_offer  customer  amount
0    $10                 -2         1     -10
1    $32                 -1         1     -32
2    $43                  0         1       0
3    $23                  1         1      23
4    $54                  2         1      54
5    $21                 -1         2     -21
6    $23                  0         2       0
7    $87                  1         2      87
8    $12                 -3         3     -12
9    $83                 -2         3     -83
10   $65                 -1         3     -65
11   $21                  0         3       0
12   $80                  1         3      80
13   $67                  2         3      67
14   $11                  3         3      11
```

- Calculate 'customer' column using `cumsum`, `shift` and `eq` and `add` to start at customer 1.
- Calculate 'amount' using string manipulation and multiply by `np.sign`
  'month from offer'
- `sum` 'amount' with `groupby` 'customer'

Answer (score 2):

In Excel, you can insert a helper column that looks at the sign and determines if the sign is different to the row above and then increments a counter number.

Hard code a customer ID of 1 into the first row of data, then calculate the rest.

```
=IF(AND(SIGN(A3)=-1,SIGN(A3)<>SIGN(A2)),B2+1,B2)
```

[image]

Copy the results and paste as values, then you can use them to aggregate your data

Comment: I like this method for calculating customer +1.

Answer (score 2):

Use `pandas.Series.diff` with `cumsum` to create pseudo user id:

```
s = df["months_from_offer"].diff().lt(0).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     0
5     1
6     1
7     1
8     2
9     2
10    2
11    2
12    2
13    2
14    2
Name: months_from_offer, dtype: int64
```

Then use `pandas.Series.clip` to make the series either -1, 0, or 1, then do multiplication:

```
spend = (df["spend"] * df["months_from_offer"].clip(-1, 1))
```

Then use `groupby.sum` with the psuedo id `s`:

```
spend.groupby(s).sum()
```

Final output:

```
months_from_offer
0    35
1    66
2    -2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

Create id

```
s = df['months_from_offer'].iloc[::-1].cumsum().eq(0).iloc[::-1].cumsum()
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     2
6     2
7     2
8     3
9     3
10    3
11    3
12    3
13    3
14    3
Name: months_from_offer, dtype: int32
```

Then `assign`  it

```
df['id']=s
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you wanted to read an excel file using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheetname='yoursheet')

pre  = 0
post = 0
for i in df.index:
    if df['months_from_offer'][i] < 0:
        pre  += int(df['spend'][i])
    if df['months_from_offer'][i] > 0:
        post += int(df['spend'][i])
dif = post - pre
```

If you would like to read the data for each customer

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheetname='yoursheet')

customers = list[]
last = None
pre  = 0
post = 0
for i in df.index:
    if last is not None and abs(last + df['months_from_offer'][i]) > 1:
        customers.append(post - pre)
        pre  = 0
        post = 0
    if df['months_from_offer'][i] < 0:
        pre  += int(df['spend'][i])
    if df['months_from_offer'][i] > 0:
        post += int(df['spend'][i])
    last = df['months_from_offer'][i]
```

Or you can use a dict to name a customer. The way I separated the customers is when 2 months are more than (int) 1 from apart, there must be another person's record starting.